# image is not downloading on a button click i.e placed inside the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am unable to download the image on a button click.. i had placed the button inside the grid to download the respective image..  below is my code.

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select FileName,Extentions, FileContent from Documents where ID=" + id;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["FileContent"];
                contentType = sdr["Extentions"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["FileName"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What do the request/response look like in Fiddler?  How is it not working?  We need a lot more diagnostic information.

Comment: The code is running successfully from tip to end.. it is not giving any error. But the image is not downloading too.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `CommandText` to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select FileName,Extentions, FileContent from Documents where ID=@Id";
```

And reader reading to this:

```
 while(sdr.Read())
 {
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["FileContent"];
                contentType = sdr["Extentions"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["FileName"].ToString();
 }
```

**EDIT :**  To test, I have used the following code to get file from my disk instead of DataBase:

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
    byte[] bytes;
    string fileName, contentType;

    // Test code  to download 123.sql file from C:\
    bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\123.sql");
    contentType = ".sql";
    fileName = "123.sql";
    //string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString;
    //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    //{
    //    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    //    {
    //        cmd.CommandText = "select FileName,Extentions, FileContent from Documents where ID=" + id;
    //        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
    //        cmd.Connection = con;
    //        con.Open();
    //        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    //        {
    //            sdr.Read();
    //            bytes = (byte[])sdr["FileContent"];
    //            contentType = sdr["Extentions"].ToString();
    //            fileName = sdr["FileName"].ToString();
    //        }
    //        con.Close();
    //    }
    //}
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contentType;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", contentType);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

**EDIT 2 :** [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0dWZsdGNVVjRTbUU/edit?usp=sharing) is a link of the test Project I have used.

Comment: You have to debug. Put a break point at `Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);` and see the value of bytes. If it is null (I suspect so), then set a break point at `Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);` , get the sql, replace @Id with id value and run the query in sssms.

Comment: I have replaced your database reading part with `bytes = File.ReadAllBytes( "C:\\123.sql");` and it is downloading 123.sql file from my disk. What is the size of `bytes`? Is it too big?

Comment: its giving the size 3059

Comment: I have added test code. You can try with physical file. If it works for you, then the sql data has issue.

Comment: You can download a copy of my test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i8p65gmkp0dWZsdGNVVjRTbUU/edit?usp=sharing). There's a backup of the db I have used for test. It is working fine!